# check request URL in apache webserver

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to check whether request URL is empty or it will start with /test

Eaxmple:

if I access www.example.com it should redirect to www.example.com/test

if the URL already have www.abc.com/test no redirection required.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  example.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/test
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://example.com/test/$1  [R=301,L,NC]
```

any modifications required to check request_URL is null?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows little effort.

Comment: Please try something. Read [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html). Look at [the tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/mod-rewrite/info) for some examples.

Comment: I do tried and updated the ticket

Comment: You can match the beginning and the end of the string with `^` and `$`. The condition with http_host is not required, and you should escape dots that are meant to be literal dots in regexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s\/(?:test\/?)?\s
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://example.com/test/$0 [R=301,L,NC]
```